# ¿Como puedo configurar vue y vue router con Vite en laravel 9?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vite

Llevo dos días intentando configurar una api rest de laravel 9 con vite. con un frontend en vue 3 pero no sé como integrar vue en la aplicación. Toda la documentación que he encontrado es con laravel mix.

He visto que la gente configura webpack.mix.js añadiendo al final de mix.js(...).postcss(...). la gente le añade .vue(). y luego hacen `npm run watch`

Hay algo parecido en vite?

Soy principante en php y en desarrollo web.

Comment: es obligatorio integrar vue en laravel? yo te recomendaria que fueran 2 proyectos independientes, donde laravel haga el papel de una API y vue solo maneje el frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que ahora la configuración se debe hacer en un nuevo archivo llamado `vite.config.js` en la raíz del proyecto (puedes borrar `webpack.mix.js` y `webpack.config.js`).

Debes instalar también los plugins oficiales de Laravel y Vue con:

`npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin`

y

`npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-vue`

Y ahora dentro del `vite.config.js` poner algo como

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
        vue({
             template: {
                 transformAssetUrls: {
                     base: null,
                     includeAbsolute: false,
                 },
             },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Esto es parte de la guía oficial de migración de Laravel Mix a Vite, la puedes revisar en [este enlace](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-laravel-mix-to-vite) (puede ser algo complicado si es la primera vez que trabajas con esos archivos, pero hay muchas otras guías).